# .htaccess 404 error when accessing file without extension

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have this simple htaccess file that should bring every request to index.php?site=

The problem is, when there is a file (like test.php) in the folder of the htaccess and the url is domain.com/test it will throw a standard "404 not found" error.

How can i fix this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?site=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: And _what_ error does it throw? Or are we meant to _guess_?

Comment: Let me try a guess: "file `index.php` does not exist!"

Comment: Since if that file _would_ exist then you certainly _would_ have posted the important parts of what it contains here...

Comment: It's standing in the headline. It gives an 404 Not Found error. Index.php exists, the funny thing is, it will just throw an error if the URL is a file name, without extension (No matter how the file name is). So if there is a file in my root directory with the name login.php i can't access domain.com/login/, because it is throwing the 404 error. Everything else works just fine.

Comment: Maybe you have _another_ internal redirection somewhere rewriting similar. Since you here test against `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`, which is not altered by such other redirection. Question is what throws the 404, That is why I asked for the content of the routing script. I could imagine it throws a 404 if a page referred to does not exist...

Answer (score 2):

For people coming here in 2019, I came across the same issue.
The cause is the mod negociation from Apache which behaves as following when multiviews is enabled:

> If the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that document.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews

You can disable the multiviews option in your .htaccess as follow :

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Or also in your apache config file if you have granted it:

```
<Directory "/var/www/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?site=$1 [QSA,L]
```

> Remove the `RewriteBase /`

Otherwise, It will redirect to your root folder.

For Example :

> - If the directory path is   **c:/{app}/{htdocs|www}/project/**
> - Then it will be accessible by **http://127.0.0.1/project/**
> - And you want to redirect **http://127.0.0.1/project/abc** to
>     **http://127.0.0.1/project/index.php?site=abc**
>
> But it is redirecting to **http://127.0.0.1/index.php?site=abc** when you add  **`RewriteBase /`**  So remove it

Comment: Sadly that's not the issue. Even with removed RewriteBase it still comes up with the 404. The Project lays in the Root directory (of the user) so it is correct. Also, like mentioned, it works when there is no file with the name. domain.com/test works, because there is no test.EXTENSION file. But domain.com/login doesn't work, because there is a login.php in the same folder. I mean i could just move the files to a different directory, but that shouldn't be needed, right? I wanna understand what causes this "bug"

Comment: @KevinLienkamp, I checked it in my host and found it is working for me. That is the only reason i made an answer here. I thought it may work for him. Thanks for the point.